# Blazor WebAssembly App unable to call HTTP PATCH WEB API method

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a Blazor WebAssembly app in .NET 5. Through this app I am calling web api methods. All the methods are called successfully **except one** which is the HTTP PATCH method where I get the following error message.

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation/4' from
> origin 'https://localhost:44366' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Method Patch is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in
> preflight response.

The images shows the error:
[image]

***When I call the same HTTP Patch method from different app which is built in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC then there is no problem at all.
I have also called the same HTTP Patch method from another app built in Blazor Server (.NET 5) with no problem.***

The API already has CORS integrated that's why other methods are getting called. But not the HTTP Pacth one.

My code that is calling HTTP Pacth is simple and is shown below:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation/" + Id),
        Method = new HttpMethod("Patch"),
        Content = new StringContent("[{ \"op\":\"replace\", \"path\":\"Name\", \"value\":\"" + ReservationData.Name + "\"},{ \"op\":\"replace\", \"path\":\"StartLocation\", \"value\":\"" + ReservationData.StartLocation + "\"}]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Why is the problem happening?

Comment: Since MVC calls and server-side Blazor calls, are not initiated by a client application CORS configuration doesn't matter for them. Before the PATCH request, you should see an OPTIONS request. Could you share the result of this request and/or, if you have access to the API, its CORS configuration?.

Comment: The API has CORS implmented. I tested the api by calling the same http patch method from JavaScript code and it worked in this case. Only the probelm is coming in Blazor WebAssembly app.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that blazor cannot use the patch verb, maybe there was even a GitHub issue for ms to add such support to c# but for now maybe js interop was needed. I may be wrong though, and I'm on mobile now

Comment: I know that sometimes CORS messages can be confusing, and you made the point that a js client could execute the PATCH operation. However, have you checked if the OPTIONS response really allows a PATCH? Does the OPTIONS response arrive? Since the browser rejected to send the PATCH request, you should really investigate the OPTIONS request and response.